# Hard time compiling tess-two for android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ocr, tess-two

I'm trying to build eyes-two from the tess-two project using android studio. I did the 
ndk-build
android ...
ant release
stuff for tess-two and eyes-two, imported eyes-two, configured ndk.dir path and all, but, while build I get the following error message:

```
allheaders.h: No such file or directory

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/italomaia/.apps/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/italomaia/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/build/intermediates/ndk/release/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-8 NDK_OUT=/home/italomaia/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/italomaia/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/build/intermediates/ndk/release/lib APP_ABI=all
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    In file included from /home/italomaia/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/writefile.cpp:17:0:
/home/italomaia/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
     #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [$HOME/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/build/intermediates/ndk/release/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/tesstwo/$HOME/workspace/eyes-two/tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/writefile.o] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958943/missing-allheaders-h-in-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

You should build it using the instructions from here.  https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master 
I had to slightly modify the instructions.
To build the latest tess-two code, run the following commands in the terminal:

`git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
cd tess
cd tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path . --target 13`

To build eyes-two, additionally run the following:

`cd ..
cd eyes-two
ndk-build
android update project --path . --target 13`

from there I opened android studio, File->import Sample and imported the Hello jni sample. after that was set up and compiling in android studio, I did File->New->Import Module pointed it at the tess-two directory selected all the defaults. at that point it gave me errors because of gradle issues. So I made this gradle file for the tess-two module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }


    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }

}
```

Then it built successfully

Comment: Hello, did u build successfully for arm64-v8a? Because I got this error, can u help?

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.halosolutions..../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.halosolutions..../lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "liblept.so"

Comment: Actually after trying it again, it did not build successfully an Android studio but I built the native c code outside of Android studio and copy the .so files and the java files into the project and ran the android app successfully.