# Missing allheaders.h in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract, leptonica

I am following the tutorial from [this tesseract tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) and had everything go smoothly up until my actual running of the Java code. When I try

```
new TessBaseApi();
```

It throws the following error

```
Error Code: 2
Output:
In file included from tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/box.cpp:17:0:
tesstwo/src/main/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
           ^
compilation terminated.
make: ***
```

I have looked into `/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src/src` and find the `allheaders.h` file there. I have a feeling my paths are wrong, but I've tried almost everything and no avail. What's the issue?

Comment: Just to mention - the path in the error message does NOT match the patch you cite "/src/src"

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, but the error occurred in common.h, but the allheaders.h file it's looking for (at least what I suspect) is in the "/src/src" folder.

Comment: What operating system are you using, and which version of the Android NDK are you using? Did you follow the build instructions _exactly_? At what point do you see this error?

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.9.5; I'm using android-ndk-r10d; So, I did deviate from the instructions at one point. On the command `android update project --path .` It said that it didn't know which project to set and recommended an additional tag which I found the solution to on another StackOverflow. Following this, because I'm not using Eclipse, I assumed Eclipse projects are similar to IntelliJ modules, so I used `Import Module` and added the module to my project. When I start writing Java code, this is where the error happens. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this problem with Android Studio. After googling some more i found this issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74132

Apparently the NDK plugin generates it's own Android.mk file and ignore any existing one, so the recommended way is to run ndk-build to generate the native .so files.

When I used ndk-build in the tess-two directory it compiles just fine and the .so files is created.

How you can include native libraries in gradle and android studio is described in this post: [Add pre-built .so files in project using Android Gradle plugin 0.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900814/add-pre-built-so-files-in-project-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-7-3)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle

But do not delete libs directory!

Set `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersio` to the same values as in project `buil.gradle`

I also change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'`

Answer (score 1):

At some point Android Studio suggests to set 
`jni.srcDirs = []`

leading to following sourceSets in the gradle.build of my tess-two library project

```
sourceSets.main {
    manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
}
```

With correct src path entered here this actualy works

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But slight modification in above code worked for me. I have posted it as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works for you but in my case, here's what I've done:

1. In common.h: change `#include <allheaders.h>` into `#include <src/src/allheaders.h>`.
2. In the library project build.gradle: add this

```
sourceSets{
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ppl, After struggling a day.. finally got the solution

In build.gradle of tess-two module add the below code:

```
  sourceSets.main {
    manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
}
```

Main thing is please check manually weather all those file paths specified in above code exists in tess-two module!!

Check in which path "liblept.so" and other **".so" files** exist in tess-two library. For me it was inside /tesstwo/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a . Hence i have made jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs'] in above code. Hope it helps !!