# tess-two import in android sdk build error in windows

Tags: android-studio, tess-two

I have build the project vie steps in the git download page
https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#build
I have installed ndk/sdk an configured in my path environment,
also i have add ndk path in project local.properties. Here is my project build log, after i had add the tess-two lib as externel project into my

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :tesstwo:compileDebugSources, :tesstwo:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:clean
:tesstwo:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:compileLint
:tesstwo:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:checkReleaseManifest
:tesstwo:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tesstwo:compileReleaseAidl
:tesstwo:compileReleaseRenderscript
:tesstwo:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:tesstwo:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:mergeReleaseAssets
:tesstwo:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:generateReleaseResources
:tesstwo:packageReleaseResources
:tesstwo:processReleaseManifest
:tesstwo:processReleaseResources
:tesstwo:generateReleaseSources
:tesstwo:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:tesstwo:compileReleaseJava
:tesstwo:packageReleaseJar
:tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk
In file included from C:\Users\Julian\AndroidStudioProjects\Jtess\tesstwo\src\main\jni\com_googlecode_leptonica_android\box.cpp:17:0:
C:\Users\Julian\AndroidStudioProjects\Jtess\tesstwo\src\main\jni\com_googlecode_leptonica_android\common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h: No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\Julian\AndroidStudioProjects\Jtess\tesstwo\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/tesstwo/C_\Users\Julian\AndroidStudioProjects\Jtess\tesstwo\src\main\jni\com_googlecode_leptonica_android\box.o] Error 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':tesstwo:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Julian\Downloads\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 38.843 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing allheaders.h in Android Studio Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958943/missing-allheaders-h-in-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 9):

The steps you followed to compile Tesseract OCR works only on eclipse,
 If you want to use it on Android Studio, follow these steps

> 1) Download and install the ndk from here
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html. I had some
>   trouble with its path in following steps so i put it in “C:\”.
>
> 2) Add that path to environment variables of the system (eg:
>   “C:\android_ndk_r10d”) and then reboot so your machine can find it.
>
> 3) Download “tess-two-master” from here
>   https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two, extract it (for example in “C:\”)
>   and rename it in “tess”.
>
> 4) Open “tess” folder and then open “tess-two” folder. Click on a
>   blank space while pressing the shift button and select “Open command
>   window here”.
>
> 5) Write “ndk-build” and wait until it completes (about 20min).
>
> 6) Go back in the parent folder, select “eyes-two” folder and again
>   click on a blank space while pressing the shift button in order to
>   open the command window.
>
> 7) Write “ndk-build” and wait.
>
> 8) Write “android update project –target 1 –path C:\tess\tess-two”. Of
>   course I assume your “tess” folder is located in “C:\”
>
> 9) Write “ant release”. IF IT COMPLAINS go where you change your
>   system environment variables as you did in step 2 and ADD a new
>   variable with name “JAVA_HOME” and value the path to your jdk (eg:
>   “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40″)
>
> 10) Open a completely new Android Studio project and follow these
>   instructions
>   https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle from
>   section “Configure tess-two with gradle” but for safety don’t delete
>   any folder or file even if he suggests to do so. I had some trouble
>   with “build.gradle” file in “libraries\tess-two” directory, but it is
>   sufficient to change some value on it. In my case I have:
>
> “`classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0′” instead of
>   “classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+’` ”
>
> and
>
> ”
>
> ```
> compileSdkVersion 21
> buildToolsVersion “21.0.2”
> defaultConfig {
> minSdkVersion 15
> targetSdkVersion 21
> }
> ```
>
> ”
>
> instead of
>
> ”
>
> ```
> compileSdkVersion 19
> buildToolsVersion “19.0.3”
>
> defaultConfig {
> minSdkVersion 8
> targetSdkVersion 19}
> ```
>
> ”.
>
> Note that the last step means you have to go in “File -> Project
>   Structure -> Select a module from the left subwindow -> Dependencies
>   (last tab) ->Press the green “+” on your right -> Module Dependency ->
>   OK”
>
> 11) Download this project
>   https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR and copy&paste in
>   your new project the code in these files:
>   “SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java”, “main.xml”, “strings.xml”. Of course
>   your files may have different names (in my case “MainActivity.java”,
>   “activity_main.xml”, “strings.xml”) so some renaming in the code may
>   be necessary. Also open your “AndroidManifest.xml” and add at the end
>   (but before “/manifest”) what you find between “/application” and
>   “/manifest” in the just downloaded “AndroidManifest.xml” (it means
>   that you have to add “uses-permissions” and “uses-feature” tag).
>
> 12) Download from here
>   https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list the file in the
>   language you prefer (eg: tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz ), extract it
>   and locate the file “yourLanguage.traineddata” (eg:
>   “eng.traineddata”). Forget for a moment your Android Studio IDE, open
>   the folder of your project and go in “app–>src–>main”. Create here a
>   new folder and name it “assets”. Open it and create another folder
>   named “tessdata”. Put there your .traineddata file.

Source: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181

Comment: Great answer :) you are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

Before see the answer download latest "android ndk" and install or extract it on C:, folder path should be like this; "C:\android-ndk-r10e"

Then add the ndk path (C:\android-ndk-r10e) to the path variable's value in the environment variable(System variable) which left my "path" variable like this

Settings --> System --> Advenced System Settings --> System Variables

[image: Settings --> System --> Advenced System Settings --> System Variables]

After set this settings you can follow the intsructions in the link below for Android Studio on Windows Operating Systems;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882613/1897454

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. First of all You have to give your NDK path in **local.properties** of your app.

```
e.g. ndk.dir=/home/user/bin/android_ndk/android-ndk-r10e
```

Then in my **build.gradle** file I had something like this for calling ndk build command.

```
commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
```

I'v change it to

```
commandLine '/home/user/bin/android_ndk/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
```

I gave full path of NDK build. Hope it'll help you.