# API to extract text from a image for Android Mobile

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to extract text from a picture taken in Android Mobile through some API. Will Google Vision help me with that? I used OCR too but I felt that the output is not accurate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hey for OCR you need [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) library. [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) is working example of ocr. And here is another [link](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) for this example. and for documentation how to create this project try [this one](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/). [textfairy](https://github.com/renard314/textfairy) is one of the best working example. try it :)
other great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882613/4545142)